# Proof involving functions.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Consider two functions $f\colon A \to B$ and $g\colon B \to C$.  How can I prove the following?

- If $f$ and $g$ are one-to-one, then the composition function $g \circ
     f$  is one-to-one.
- If $f$ and $g$ are onto functions, then $g \circ f$ is an onto
  function.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Do you know what one-to-one or onto means?

Answer (score 1):

For injectivity of $g\circ f$ you have to check that
$$g(f(x))=g(f(y))\rightarrow x=y$$
holds for every $x,y\in A$. Use first that $g$ is one-to-one, then that $f$ is one to one.

For surjectivity, given $z$ arbitrary in $C$ you are requested to find an element $x\in A$  such that $g(f(x))=z$. Take a pre-image $y\in B$ of $z$ via $g$, using surjectivity of $g$ and then take a preimage $x\in A$ of $y$ using surjectivity of $f$. Check that $g(f(x))=z$